# Add an Event to Google Calender by Sending an Email

Tags: gmail, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I want to add an event to a google calendar by sending an email.

In fact, I created a calendar and i have the id of the calendar `#hash#@group.calendar.google.com` 
My idea was to send an ICS to that id but it does not work.

Example of the ics:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180910T100000
DTEND:20180910T120000
DTSTAMP:20180831T082208
ORGANIZER:mailto:#####@cozynergy.com
UID:1770733000016589223
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:#hash#@group.calendar.google.com
DESCRIPTION:my description
LOCATION:LOCATION
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:HEY THIS IS MY EMAIL TEST :)
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: @abielita It is just a nodemailer used with NodeJs but it is not important.
No errors returned, the problem is the ICS structure and if it is possible or not to send an ical event to a google calendar : ```#hash#@group.calendar.google.com```

BECAUSE, my event cannot be seen on my calendar...but when I send the ics to a physical gmail address for example...I can see the event.
Do you see what I mean ? the code for this question is ICS and I put an example in my question ^^